# How to change Custom Cell's UILabel Text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uilabel

I have a table view with a custom protoype cell and the cell has 3 different labels on it. How do I get access to these labels? I need to change their texts. I've searched around everywhere and haven't found something that helps me in this case. I have the below code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"basicCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //change cell's 3 labels' text here

    return cell;


}
```

How can I access the above cell's 3 different labels that it has?

Comment: Make a custom class for your cell, then you do it the same way as any other view. You make IBOutlets to the labels (or properties if you make the labels in code), and use those to set the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make a class that is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, and set the custom cell's class to the class you made. Then you want to link the labels using `IBOutlet`s in the cell to the subclass you made.

Finally, in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you should cast the cell to your new subclass so you get access to those `IBOutlet`s. Assuming your outlets are named `someLabelOutlet1`, `someLabelOutlet2`, and `someLabelOutlet3`, do the following *after you finished subclassing*.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    SomeTableViewCellSubclass *cell = (SomeTableViewCellSubclass *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"basicCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.someLabelOutlet1.text = @"sometext"
    cell.someLabelOutlet2.text = @"sometext"
    cell.someLabelOutlet3.text = @"sometext"

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You don't do it there. You need to create a new `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Comment: Now the table displays nothing :(

Comment: Did you link the labels to the `UITableViewCell` subclass?

Comment: Wait, don't we have to change the return type of the method as well?

Comment: No of course not. Check if you really subclassed it properly and did everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you can access these labels

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    CustomCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    if (!cell) {
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    // set common properties here
    cell.lbl1.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    cell.lbl1.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:16.0];
    }
    cell.lbl1.text=@"lbl1Txt";
    cell.lbl2.text=@"lbl2Txt";
    cell.lbl3.text=@"lbl3Txt";
    return cell;
}
```